# Problems with launch qiskit

Tags: python, qiskit

I have installed a Python 3.7.2, download anaconda and visual studio code. Install qiskit sdk 0.5.3, and qiskit for Python via `pip install qiskit` But when I launch my first test program from https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra I receieved a couple of messages like

```
> "message": "Instance of 'QuantumCircuit' has no 'h' member", 
> "message": "Instance of 'QuantumCircuit' has no 'cx' member", 
> "message": "Instance of 'QuantumCircuit' has no 'measure' member",
```

What I do wrong?

This is my code:

```
from qiskit import *
q = QuantumRegister(2)
c = ClassicalRegister(2)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q, c)
qc.h(q[0])
qc.cx(q[0], q[1])
qc.measure(q, c)
backend_sim = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
result = execute(qc, backend_sim).result()
print(result.get_counts(qc))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717852/why-python-doesnt-see-the-members-of-quantumcircuit-class-qiskit). The answer given here is that they are linter warnings probably produced by your IDE, they are not errors with your code - your code looks good to me!